# implementing chart like Dextool's chart for my react.js application

Tags: ethereumjs, react, defi, graphql

I'm gonna implement chart into my react.js application.
Chart method should be similar to dextools. Now I try to use GraphQL to retrieve all trading histories. And also I'm gonna use OHLC react chart package.
Is there any better way than this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GraphQL to retrieve trading histories is a good approach, as it allows you to retrieve only the data you need, which can improve performance.

As for the OHLC react chart package, it's a popular and well-documented package, so it should be a good choice. However, there are other charting libraries available for React that you may want to consider, such as Recharts and Victory. Ultimately, the best choice will depend on your specific needs and preferences.